# Used wrong branch number in last 3 digits of SWIFT Code

Tags: money-transfer

I am sending from my Canadian bank to her bank Wells Fargo in California. I was supposed to use the universal swift code WFBIUS6S. But I accidentally used WFBIUS6SLAX. (For the specific Los Angeles branch) The name and account numbers are correct. Will it be sent back because of this mistake. Or will it be fine because it’s the same bank?

Comment: Have you tried contacting your bank?

Comment: Did your payment went thru eventually?

Answer (score 1):

First, check to see if the money is in Wells Fargo.  If not, contact Wells Fargo.
Some banks have different branches with different codes, but the transfer might go through, properly, depending on the branch.